# How to get user-independent Library path for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, delphi, path, c++builder, c++builder-xe6

Using XE6, the Embarcadero documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetLibraryPath) states that TPath::GetLibraryPath () "Returns the path to a directory to store any data that your application needs store, **regardless of the user**".

Yet, in the Sample Path table, they list OS X's for this function as

> /Users/username/Library

which seems user-specific. The first question is whether this is, in fact, the correct folder to use to store data regardless of the user. The second question is - if not - how to get the folder to the user-non-specific Library in OS X?

Comment: From the docs: *On Windows, it points to the folder that contains the executable file.* That sounds really useful. One does wonder about FMX. Don't the able folk at Emba suffer from any embrassment at all?

Comment: don't use TPath. How about you just write a function to return what you want, using some {$ifdef} code. I would think the OS X define returning '/Library/YourCompany/AppName' would be something you could generate yourself, and for the Windows side, you'd want to invoke the `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` with whatever `CSIDL_` constant you need to find 'c:\programData' or its equivalent, then add 'YourCompany\AppName' to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this for retrieving this folder.

```
uses
  Macapi.Foundation, Macapi.Helpers;

type
  ENSFileManagerException = class(Exception);

function GetFolder_ProgramData: string;
var
  FileManager: NSFileManager;
  ID: Cardinal;
  Domain: Cardinal;
  Url: NSURL;
  Bundle: NSBundle;
begin
  ID := NSApplicationSupportDirectory; // ProgramData on Windows
  Domain := NSLocalDomainMask;

  FileManager := TNSFileManager.Wrap(TNSFileManager.OCClass.defaultManager);
  Url := FileManager.URLForDirectory(ID, Domain, nil, False, nil);
  if URL <> nil then
    Result := NSStrToStr(Url.path)
  else
    raise ENSFileManagerException.CreateFmt('Could not retrieve folder for ID %d', [ID]); //Error.localizedDescription.UTF8String);
end;
```